# What to say at a wake for a professor's wife?

Tags: etiquette, singapore

The professor taught me a course many years ago, while the wife died in a road accident that I learned about in the news.

What should I say at the wake? Can I ask about the professor's research and work, or should I focus on non-academic things?

Edit:

- I don't know the professor's wife.
- The wake is, as far as I can tell, public. An email was circulated among the department with details, and the email did not say "keep within department".
- Country: Singapore

Comment: Just wondering: why are you attending at all? From the question, it sounds like you were one of many students many years ago and haven't kept in touch. But personalities and cultures differ; perhaps this is normal where you are.

Comment: @cag51 If I'm being honest, it's because he supervised a close friend once, and the friend is attending. That said, I feel like what you wrote is even more reason to attend - it should be always better to keep in touch than to not keep in touch, and the professor did teach me once (although I did rather worse at the course than I should have, oops).

Comment: @Allure a wake is generally not a social event.  You can keep in touch via email, conferences, dinner invitations, etc. - not a wake.  I would expect such a wake to be quite emotional, possibly even devastating given the circumstances.  I wouldn't plan on saying anything beyond: "I am a former student of yours, Allure.  I'm sorry for your loss".

Comment: @Gauss I don’t think Allure is mistaking the wake for a social event. My interpretation of “it is better to keep in touch” is that Allure thinks this is a way to show support to the bereaved professor. Personally I agree, people in mourning typically appreciate a broad show of support including from relatively remote parts of their social and professional circles. One does not need to be a close friend to reach out and express empathy to a person mourning a loved one.

Comment: @Gauss can you explain how wakes are like in your corner of the world? In the wakes I've been to, there are many tables set up. We go, talk to the deceased's immediate family, pay our respects at the coffin, and then settle down at one of the tables to chat. In that sense it is very much a social event not dissimilar to a marriage, except the overall mood is much more suppressed and the topics talked about are more macabre. Still, eventually people stop talking about death, and talk about work, life, etc.

Comment: I live in the UK. I've certainly seen open "any former student can attend" invitations to (usually) funerals when an academic died, but never if their spouse died.

Comment: For what it's worth, the absolute last thing I would appreciate at a time of intense grief is some random student from years ago showing up and forcing me to make small talk/be polite. I would feel an obligation to talk to them and deal with them and that would be the last thing I'd want to do while grieving my wife. And if I were to feel that this student came to my wife's _wake_ as a way of "keeping in touch", I would never want to set eyes on the student again in my life.

Comment: @Marianne013  I agree. Most countries today have Memorial/RIP websites where announcements of deaths and funeral arrangement details may be read and where condolences may be written up. For more distant and purely professional relationships, this might be a suitable avenue.

Comment: @Allure I don’t have any thoughts to offer, sorry. This is very location- and culture-specific, I’d suggest consulting friends or colleagues where you are for advice.

Comment: The reception *after* the funeral (if there is one) is a better place for such socializing.  The wake is supposed to be a somber event for consoling the family and paying respects to the deceased.

Comment: @Allure I am in the United States, but it may be more dependent on religion.  In my experience losing a close relative, the people attending pay respects to the coffin and then came to me/my family to express condolences.  It's possible the other guests socialized quietly after doing so or outside, but I was too busy trying to keep it together.  Perhaps it's best to clarify and say that I don't think the immediate family (i.e., your former Prof) will be up for socializing.

Comment: Here in Ireland, wakes and funerals are a much bigger deal than they are in the UK. (It's one of the biggest cultural differences between two such near neighbours.) But still I would be inclined to go to the funeral, not the wake: it's less personal, more public.

Comment: "What's a good boat for a mathematician?"

Comment: @TRiG - At my wife's father's funeral in Lancashire, we met a middle-aged Irish lady, a distant cousin. She got out a hip flask and offered us each a swig (which we took). She confided that she 'only came to these things for the wakes'. She kept whispering wisecracks and sarcastic remarks all through the (Catholic) service. We couldn;t stop laughing.  At the wake she located the Jamesons and kept us topped up. She was just exactly what we needed, and we were so glad that she was there.

Comment: >>The wake is, as far as I can tell, public.  Unless this is a Singaporean thing, this is odd. Funerals are public (they're just church services, after all), but wakes are generally an invited event.

Comment: We hosted a wake for my grandmother just the other da, @mcalex. Friends turned up earlier in the day and made a legion of sandwiches. There were cakes and buns. They also supplied extra tea cups and an urn. The next door neighbours supplied four extra chairs. At the time of the wake itself, many  many friends and neighbours dropped by. We certainly didn't invite anyone.

Comment: @TRiG, a) *generally*, b) did the friends & neighbours know about the event previoulsy? if they did, I'd suggest providing that information amounts to an implicit invitation unless you tack on '.. so you can't come around because the house will be full on that day' when you tell them.  If they didn't know and were just being neighbourly and friendly, my congrats on having such positive relations with so many people. :-)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You should express condolences for the loss of the person... in the time of loss of a partner, academic stuff is not primary. Don't even mention academic stuff. If you say anything at all, just tell your sympathies for your professor's loss of their life partner.

Comment: This is good general advice. Most people say way too much when offering condolences. All you need to and should say is something along the lines of "I'm so sorry" or "I'm sorry for your loss". If you know the person well and are friends you can offer to help (food, listening, etc.). People often accidentally cause unknowing emotional harm when they try to say things to reduce the other's grief. Grieving people usually just want to know that you care about their grief; they don't want you to try to eliminate it because you can't, and trying will often make it much worse. So this +100.

Answer (score 41):

As others have noted, a wake is not a social event. If you have no reason to be there, don't go. It is an event for those who were close to the deceased person and/or are close to those they left behind.

But if you need to go, the English language has phrases that work well in this context: "I am very sorry for your loss" or "My condolences". In all likelihood, the professor will spend time with those he knows well, and your only contact will be in a line of people offering their condolences to the husband. You are not expected to make small talk there -- you shake that person's hand, say your sentence, and move on to let others in line have their turn. If for whatever reason, the professor chooses to talk to you at a later time, repeat the sentence and then let him choose the topic of conversation.

Comment: _If you have no reason to be there, don’t go._ This is tautologically true but does not actually support the claim of the next sentence, which I disagree with. A wake is for anyone who knows the bereaved family and wishes to express support for them at a very painful time, unless they specifically asked only for close friends to come. Thus OP absolutely can (and in my understanding, does) have a reason to be there.

Comment: Like others, I'd ask why you should be there at all. But if you must . . . Just as regards shaking hands: I think this practice - while well-intended - does no service to the bereaved as they are almost exhausted from shaking hands and hearing sympathies. Your being there with your sympathy card is enough. Don't stay to any post-wake meal, they have enough to cater for within the family and neighbors. And **no conversation** with bereaved - or anyone else who may be there but bored.

Comment: @DanRomik I disagree: "The professor taughta  class I was in many years ago" does not qualify any more to go to a wake than "I read about a radom person dying in the news today". In fact, this is exactly what happened. Don't go to a wake if you heard about it in the news. If you are close enough, you will have heard about it in a personal message.

Comment: This is a great answer. OP seems to assume a protracted conversation with the professor, which is not realistic. But if it happens, OP should listen and let the professor lead. Great answer. I also agree that if OP doesn't really know the professor and/or the professor doesn't really know OP, it may be better for OP to stay home.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what exactly is a wake?

Comment: @Nav It's ceremony after someone's death: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_(ceremony)

Comment: According to the first sentence in this Wikipedia article `A wake is a social gathering`. Why is everyone saying it's not a social event then?

Answer (score 24):

Without knowing where you are in the world it's hard to answer. My answer is therefore biased towards the German (and Catholic) way.

##### Before deciding to go

Were you especially close to this professor? Was he a special advisor to you or did you work for him? Did you know his wife? Is it an open wake? If the answer to most of those questions is "no", then don't go.

You said your friend is planning to attend and that's why you want to go. If that's your main motivation, don't go. You two are presumably adults-- you don't need a buddy system. If your friend was invited they should go alone.

For example, I did not go with my partner to a funeral for his best friend's mom. I knew her, but we were not close. My partner was there to show support for his best friend and that was that.

Using a wake to "keep in touch" would not be well-received by most people where I live. Wakes are about remembering the deceased for the benefit of the bereaved.

If you want to reach out to your professor send a hand-written card with your sympathies.

##### If you still want to go

Two things to keep in mind:

1. Your professor has lost his spouse in a sudden and traumatic way. Most of his day will be about accepting condolences and possibly comforting/being comforted by those close to him. If you do go, keep condolences short and to the point. Getting condolences all day is tiring. Don't bother trying to talk about academic stuff with your prof. He just lost his wife. That is time for him to be with his family.
2. Other bereaved will be there too and if you end up staying for a while, they will probably chat with you. More than likely you will be asked how you knew the deceased. If you never met her it might be awkward.

Honestly, if you didn't know his wife or him in a more personal way, it's not appropriate to go. Something similar happened to my family at a funeral for a loved one and it was very uncomfortable and exhausting.

Answer (score 16):

I disagree with some of the answers/comments that say a wake is "not a social event"; my experience of wakes is quite like OP's description in a comment:

> In the wakes I've been to, there are many tables set up. We go, talk to the deceased's immediate family, pay our respects at the coffin, and then settle down at one of the tables to chat. In that sense it is very much a social event not dissimilar to a marriage, except the overall mood is much more suppressed and the topics talked about are more macabre. Still, eventually people stop talking about death, and talk about work, life, etc.

However, it is important to note that this is a social event with quite a bit more formality to it than a mere dinner party. While it's typical in my experience to gather with close friends and family and talk about a variety of topics - some mundane (the weather, sports, TV and movies) and others connected to the deceased (favorite memories, specific things you will miss), the important thing to recognize in this situation is that *it appears OP is in an outsider position*. That is, they have a very tenuous connection to the spouse of the deceased, being merely a former student in some course.

As such, they should expect to be a very low priority for conversation by their former professor, as that person is going to be much closer to other attendees. The event is likely to be quite an awkward arrangement for this outsider person, as they may have an opportunity to say a brief phrase of condolences as others have suggested, but after that they are likely not to have much else to say to anyone else. The other attendees will be conversing with the other people there that they know, not with strangers like OP. They will likely feel interrupted and put off if it appears they are expected to make small talk with a stranger. If that leaves OP with only one other person that they are familiar with, the spouse of the deceased, that's just not a good situation for anyone.

I'd recommend not attending at all in these circumstances, unless the existing relationship is far, far more personal than the current description indicates ("The professor taught me a course many years ago").

Comment: I agree with your answer, although maybe it is hair splitting about terms. For example, I would not describe my Christmas family's dinner as a social event, although some friends of family's members may be brought in "uninvited".

Comment: @EarlGrey A social event is a place where people come primarily to socialize; that's what a wake is, at least in the US traditions I'm familiar with. It doesn't mean everyone is invited, it doesn't mean it's a place to meet new people, it doesn't mean every possible topic of conversation is suitable.

Comment: There's no preemptive answer to this question. You have to go there (or not, +1) and *read the room*.

Comment: In my experience with wakes, there are a lot of people there who don't know each other - e.g. the wife's work colleagues are not likely to know the professor's work colleagues. It also seems like some other former students are going ...

Comment: @Allure It's not that everyone needs to know everyone else, it's that everyone needs to know *someone*. You talk to the people you know, unless you're introduced by someone you know to another person.

Comment: @BryanKrause But more than that, they need to have known the person who died very well. (Or, exceptionally, be the partner of someone who did.) The OP really doesn't qualify.

Comment: @Graham In my experience a lot of people come to wakes/funerals due to their *relationship to the surviving family*, rather than the deceased, and may in fact have never met the deceased or met only in passing; however, I agree with you, that having merely been a past course student of the spouse of the deceased is not a close enough relationship. It may be appropriate for a current/former PhD student in some cases.

Comment: This answer comes the closest to acknowledging that a wake may be a very different event in Singapore than in Europe or in the US. I personally don't know what it's like in Singapore, but I'd recommend OP (if not from Singapore) to ask someone who is

Comment: Singaporean wakes can be like this. Drinking, card games, things like that.

Answer (score 6):

A wake is generally not a social event. You can keep in touch via email, conferences, dinner invitations, etc. - not a wake.

I would expect such a wake to be quite emotional, possibly even devastating given the circumstances.

I wouldn't plan on saying anything beyond: "I am a former student of yours, Allure. I'm sorry for your loss"

To put it ultra-rational: don't say anything beyond this, really nothing!
What percentage of your time did you spend with this professor in the last 3 years? Then the professor deserves to spend the same % of time of his wife's wake with you.

---

Most of this answer is from the comments section ( @Gauss ) , since comments may be deleted unexpectedly.